# How can I hide before and after element on small screen?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a site in here:
http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/
The page categorys have a before and after element (this crate a nice line category before and after).
Unfortunately if I add a very long name to the categors,  the text  can't be centered, becouse of lines.
Like in this picture:
[image]

As you can see the  `"Bloggal kapcsolatos hírek"` text is not looks good, but if I remove before and after I have enough space for move left and make looks better :)
My media query was:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .title--striped {
        font-size: 8px;
    }

    .title--striped__inwrap:before,.title--striped__inwrap:after {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the media queries (assuming you are looking for specific screen widths):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) { 
    .title--striped {
        font-size: 8px;
    }

    .title--striped__inwrap:before,.title--striped__inwrap:after {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't do the trick, I would assume it is your CSS selectors that are incorrect. If I understand what you're asking correctly, you want to hide post categories when on small screens. Looking at your code, it may be easier to do this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) { 
    .title--striped {
        font-size: 8px;
    }

    div.post__category.title--striped {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question and I can edit my answer

Comment: I think you missunderstanding something.
I whant to remove before and after pseudo tag on mobile.
But I finaly found soluiton, with `.div.post__category.title--striped::beforediv.post__category., title--striped after::{content:""}`